# SPO Classic Experience - sub sites get Modern Experience home page when created

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, classic-experience

I have an SPO site where the default site definition is set to classic experience.

Recently when creating a new subsite the home page (Get Started With Your Site) defaults to a modern home page view.

All the other list and library pages etc. display in classic mode as expected. Only the Home Page displays incorrectly.
I want the classic page to display without having to make customizations on the home page each time a new subsite is created.

Is there a setting I can check or something that can be pinpointed to explain this new page behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a subsite in the modern site, select classic site template instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note how the Modern Experiences is only enabled on lists and libraries by default now days

You'll have to use a Wiki Page to use the classic look and then customize according to your requirement.

Comment: Please Note: "All the other list and library pages etc. display in classic mode as expected. Only the Home Page displays incorrectly."